# Game Center plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension invalidated

Tags: objective-c, game-center, ios9, gamekit

If I click "cancel" on `GameCenterWindow(findMatch)` or it found a match, I have `fail:"plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension invalidated"` and nothing else. Why do I see this warning and what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: this fail only on ios 9, ios 8 work normal!

Comment: maybe problem in:  "_match.playerIDs", because playerIDs deprecated?

Comment: Please include that comment in the actual question.  Please include the code that triggers the error.

Comment: http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/ios-9-bug-update-game-center-not-working-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-1521185

Comment: Have you look for deprecated methods for GKLocalPlayer ? See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578341/ios9-gamecenter-error-plugin-com-apple-gamecenterui-gamecentermatchmakerextensi/35259783#35259783