# iOS9 Gamecenter error "plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension invalidated"

Tags: objective-c, plugins, ios9

Since the release of iOS 9, my app has now started to give me the error "plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension invalidated" anytime a user interacts with the matchmaker viewcontroller such as dismissing the matchmaker viewcontroller or establishing a match.  I have tried many different things I thought could solve the issue but have had no luck.  Can someone please help me solve this issue?  It is blocking me from continuing the development of my app on iOS 9.

Comment: I'm running into this issue now, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Thought there might have been something wrong with my Xcode so I tried running my app on another mac with a fresh install of Xcode and STILL no luck :( @Lizza

Answer (score 0):

I get this error at the point in my game when the system is preparing for a voice chat session.

The GKVoiceChatService Class reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKVoiceChatService_Class/) shows the whole system deprecated.

However, you can access the same information via [GKVoiceChat](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKVoiceChat_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKVoiceChat) with no mention of deprecation. Maybe something is halfway to being deprecated.

I wonder whether they intend us to use a different system for chat?

Comment: Dont think that is the issue since I have not implemented GKVoiceChat.  Im not sure if it is something wrong with my provisioning profile for gamecenter or something went wrong with the gamekit.framework I have installed on my machine.

Comment: I'm not convinced there is anything wrong with our apps. Maybe it's a glitch in iOS or XCode?

Comment: My matchmaking fails sometimes and returns the following error:

extension error domain error -5900